# Using perl to modify a LaTeX document

Tags: text-processing, perl

I am trying to use `perl` in order to modify a `LaTeX` document. In fact, I am trying to change the citation format from for example:

```
. \cite{poelma20113d}
```

to

```
\cite{poelma20113d}.
```

In other words, I want to find those citations which are preceded by a period and a space and replace them with blank then put the citation and then place a period after it. Could someone help me how I can do that via `perl` one liner? The reason I want to do this is that I want to change the format of my manuscript that was prepared for the Journal of Physics of Fluids to the Journal of Physical Review E.

Comment: How robust does it need to be? Do you ever have an optional argument `\cite[]{}` or an alternative macro `\citet{}`?

Comment: Actually I am changing the format of my manuscript from Physics of Fluids to Physical Review E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find and perform the swap as you're inquiring about:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/\. (\\cite.*)/$1./' afile 
\cite{poelma20113d}.
```

To have the one liner make the actual change to the file:

```
$ perl -i.bak -lpe 's/\. (\\cite.*)/$1./' afile
```

This will keep the original file in `afile.bak`. If you want to forgo having the .bak files created you can tell `perl` to not do this by omitting any argument to the `-i` switch:

```
$ perl -i -lpe 's/\. (\\cite.*)/$1./' afile
```

#### How it works

The above examples look for the following bits within each string of file `afile`.

- `\.` - looks for a literal <kbd>.</kbd>.
- `s/.../../` - searches for a pattern and replaces it with another pattern.
- `(\\cite.*)` - looks for the pattern of a literal <kbd>\</kbd> followed by the string `cite`, followed by anything else. All this is saves in a variable, `$1` because it's wrapped in parens (i.e. <kbd>(....)</kbd>). 
  **Note**: `(\\cite.*})` will stop when it reaches the right curly brace `}`. This way, the next sentence after the `LaTeX` `\cite{}` command for example in `. \cite{poelma20113d} This is the next sentence.` will be processed correctly.
- `$1.` - `$1` is what we matched in the parens, so we put that out followed by a <kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. Very efficient way. Can I know what `\. (\\cite.*)` does? I understand the first part: `\. ` which finds the period and space. I wanted to know what `(\\cite.*)` does.

Comment: @A2009 - let me know if that clears it up.

Comment: Wonderful explanation and nice formatting in "How it works". Loved it!

Comment: @A2009 - thanks for the Q, glad to of been of help!

Comment: One more question. Does `(\\cite.*)` stop when it reaches a whitespace after the curly braces at the end of cite?

Comment: @A2009 not in it's current form but it could be modified to do so like this: `(\\cite .*)`. Your example didn't show any white space.

Comment: Actually I meant does `.*` in `\cite.*` in the search command `'s/\. (\\cite.*)/$1./'` stop at the last curly braces in `. \cite{poelma20113d} This is the next sentence.`?

Comment: @A2009 - no the `.*` is greedy, it will stop at the end of a line. A curly brace could be put there to stop it though, `(\\cite.*})`.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure LaTeX can only be properly parsed with LaTeX[<sup>1</sup>](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language) and implementing LaTeX in Perl would be a real challenge. Therefore any trivial Perl solution will fail on some edge conditions. Working off of the following example

> This is cite{foo}. \cite{foo} This is cite[foo]{bar}. \cite[foo]{bar} This is citet{foo, bar}.\citet{foo, bar}

which covers a single optional argument, multiple citations, alternative forms of `\cite` that start with `\cite`, and variable amount of white space between the `.` and the `\cite`. The following `perl` expression seems to do what you need

```
perl -pe 's/(.\s*)(\\cite)([^{]*)(\[[^\]]*\])?{([^}]*)}/\2\3\4\{\5\}./g' afile
```

> This is cite{foo}\cite{foo}. This is cite[foo]{bar}\cite[foo]{bar}. This is citet{foo, bar}\citet{foo, bar}.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is that I want to change the format of my manuscript that was prepared for the Journal of Physics of Fluids to the Journal of Physical Review E.

Comment: I would be thankful if you could elaborate on the regular expression: `'s/(.\s*)(\\cite)([^{]*)(\[[^\]]*\])?{([^}]*)}/\2\3\4\{\5\}./g'`